# How to get value from top input to bottom input?

Tags: javascript, html

How to get value from top input to bottom input ?

Old code is

```
<span id="lblValue"></span>
```

but i try to add value to input type text it's not work

```
<input type="text" id="lblValue" value="">
```

How can i do ?

http://jsfiddle.net/VDd6C/744/

```
<script>
    function edValueKeyUp()
    {
        var edValue = document.getElementById("edValue");
        var s = edValue.value;

        var lblValue = document.getElementById("lblValue");
        lblValue.innerText = "The text box contains: "+s;

        //var s = $("#edValue").val();
        //$("#lblValue").text(s);    
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you really want.

Comment: `"real time value"`? What you mean?

Comment: I think he want to type on input and instantly update the label.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` does not have an `innerText` property - it has a `.value` property.

```
lblValue.value= "The text box contains: "+s;
```

Demo:    http://jsfiddle.net/VDd6C/747/

Always have your console open, you would have seen the error: `Uncaught NoModificationAllowedError: Failed to set the 'innerText' property on 'HTMLElement': The 'input' element does not support text insertion.`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
lblValue.innerText
```

to

```
lblValue.value
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VDd6C/748/)**

Inputs don't have an innerText property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to replace the

`lblValue.innerText`

to

```
lblValue.value
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `lblValue` is also an input text, use `.value` to set it:

```
<input id="edValue" type="text" onKeyUp="edValueKeyUp()"><br>
<span id="label"></span><br/>
<input type="text" id="lblValue" value="">
<script>
function edValueKeyUp() {
    var edValue = document.getElementById("edValue");
    var s = edValue.value;

    var lblValue = document.getElementById("lblValue");
    document.getElementById("label").innerText = "The text box contains: ";
    lblValue.value = s;
           // ^ .value not .innerText
    lblValue.readOnly = true; // optional

}
</script>
```